# Formula for rotating image with specified coordinates

Tags: php, rotation, formula

I have:

left-eye: x: 700, y: 800
right-eye: x: 500, y: 600
and other coordinates...

I have the coordinates of the eye centers, nose tip, mouth center. I just want the formula to rotate the image to make eyes horizontal. What is that formula in php?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine following drawing: Draw a line from left to right eye (hypothenuse). Draw a line from left eye horizontally (adjacent). Draw a line from right to down (opposite). Now you have a triangle and you can do the math. The angle of tan(phi) = opposite/adjacent.

Your example has the property, that the right eye is on the left side, so I calculate the min and max to get correct distances.

```
$lx    = 700;
$ly    = 800;
$rx    = 500;
$ry    = 810;
$minX  = min($lx, $rx);
$maxX  = max($lx, $rx);
$minY  = min($ly, $ry);
$maxY  = max($ly, $ry);
$dx    = $maxX - $minY;
$dy    = $maxY - $minY;
$angle = rad2deg(atan($dy / $dx));
```

Angle is 63.4 degree.